# Nginix configuration in local nextcloud sserver(using ngrok)

Tags: nginx, ngrok, self-hosting, nextcloud

So i was hosting a server in my home by using nextcloud.For port forwarding i used ngrok and whenever i login to my nextcloud account it gives me "ngrok-browser-warning-page".To overcome this i use nginx for reverse proxy method:
Configure Nginx for Reverse Proxy:

> **sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/ngrok**

**Inside this configuration file,**

> server{
> server_name localhost ngrok.localhost.direct;
> listen 80;
> listen 443 ssl;
> location / {
> //regular forwarding headers
> proxy_set_header X—Forwarded—For X—Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
> proxy_set_header X—Forwarded—Proto $scheme;
> proxy_set_header Host thrush—proper—kingfish.ngrok—free.app;

//this line does the actual trick

> proxy_set_header ngrok—skip—browser—warning 1;
> //forward!
> proxy_pass https://thrush—proper—kingfish.ngrok—free.app/ ;

**Enable the Nginx Site Configuration***

**> sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ngrok /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**

**Test the Configuration***

**> sudo nginx -t**

it gives me the error

so the config file written over here is correct or not idk ??
help me to fix thiss pleasse

already mentioned above[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdqMj.png)